# Mysql - enable innodb_locks_unsafe_for_binlog

Tags: mysql

According to this http://www.percona.com/blog/2006/07/12/insert-into-select-performance-with-innodb-tables/

there should be a way to enable innodb_locks_unsafe_for_binlog,

How should I do this?

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html

Comment: It says to use a command line - but here is what I get: 
 mysql --user=root --password=root1111 -A --innodb_locks_unsafe_for_binlog on prestashop2, result:
mysql: unknown option '--innodb_locks_unsafe_for_binlog'

Answer (score 1):

The documentation: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_locks_unsafe_for_binlog says that this is not a "Dynamic" variable.

> innodb_locks_unsafe_for_binlog can be set only at server startup, whereas the isolation level can be set at startup or changed at runtime.

Therefore this would be set in your my.cnf:

```
[mysqld]
innodb_locks_unsafe_for_binlog=1
```